# Skipping prompt page when using URL [cognos]

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos

I have a report with a prompt page. I want to skip the prompt page by passing the parameters in the URL ( ie &p_promptgeo=x) and setting &run.prompt=false but I just get the reprot with the default parameter of the prompt not the parameter I set in the URL (here x). 
Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your problem. I created a test report with a single parameterized filter and a prompt page with a prompt tied to the parameter. I then went into the properties of the report in the portal to grab the 'Default action URL'. I changed the run.prompt in the URL to false and appended the report parameter as you described above. Using this URL the report ran without rendering a prompt page and it passed in the value I supplied in the URL.

One thing you can try is to set a render variable on the prompt page. Have the variable check for the non-existence of the parameter (e.g. ?p_promptgeo? is null) and only render the prompt page if no value is passed in. I tested this scenario and it works, even if you have run.prompt=true.